# is fwrite a security issue in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments, gravityforms

I need to capture the stripe_customer_id to the wordpress database user meta data so that I can have a front end form that the user can use to cancel a subscription in Stripe. The user will create an account and sign up for the subscription in the same form.

I was trying to accomplish that with an action and a filter, but could not successfully do it because the user is not logged in when the Stripe subscription is created.

I found another developer to help me out, and they accomplished the end goal by writing the stripe_customer_id to a text file, logging in the user and then added the ID to the user meta data.

Can anyone tell me if the following actions in the functions.php file pose any kind of security risk?

```
add_action('gform_stripe_customer_after_create', 'save_stripe_customer_id',10,4);

function save_stripe_customer_id( $customer, $feed, $entry, $form)
{
    $fp = fopen("stripdata.txt","w");      
    fwrite($fp,$customer->id);      
    fclose($fp);
}

add_action("gform_user_registered", "autologin", 10, 4);
function autologin($user_id, $config, $entry, $password) {
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, false, '');
    $fp = fopen("stripdata.txt","r");
    $customer_id = trim(fgets($fp));
    fclose($fp);

    update_user_meta($user_id, '_stripe_customer_id',$customer_id);       
}
```

Thanks for the feedback @EdCottrell. The dev rewrote the code using a session variable. Would you mind looking at this code real quick and letting me know your thoughts?

```
// login user after they register
add_action("gform_user_registered", "autologin", 10, 4);
function autologin($user_id, $config, $entry, $password){
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, false, '');       
        update_user_meta($user_id, '_stripe_customer_id',$_SESSION['customer_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['customer_id']);       
}

add_action('gform_stripe_customer_after_create', 'save_stripe_customer_id',10,4);

function save_stripe_customer_id( $customer, $feed, $entry, $form)
{  

   // $email = rgar( $entry,'14');

    if(!session_id())
    {    
        session_start();
    }

     $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $customer->id;  

}
```

Comment: There are all sorts of problems here. You’re saving customer IDs in plain text (potentially world-readable and web-accessible, too), which is bad. You have a race/collision problem that could easily result in somebody having the wrong customer ID associated with their WordPress account, which is bad. There’s the question why you would do any of this in the first place, as opposed to just updating the metadata right away (or ASAP, using the database or at least a session variable to store the ID, either of which is better than a single text file). And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ed. Can you take a look at the new code I just posted in the original question and let me know if this is a more sure method to accomplish this?